# jQuery Ajax Post JSON - Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I need to send an API request and get a response, which I then write to the frontend in html as JSON for the time being (this is the first step, parsing to the table is step two). I'm not educated in this area, I've tried everything I found here, but it always gives me the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)".

On API Tester, the server response is correct, so I assume that the server (which I have no control) is set up correctly.

The request looks like this:

```
POST https://mmb.some-url.com:8082/api/calculators/hc/calculate

**Request**
HEADERS
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer token-code-here

**BODY**
{
  "product_id": "hc",
  "dimensions": {
    "length": 1111,
    "standard_lengths": "yes"
  },
  "heating": {
    "temp_water_in": 75,
    "temp_water_out": 65,
    "temp_room": 20
  },
  "cooling": {
    "temp_water_in": 7,
    "temp_water_out": 12,
    "temp_room": 27,
    "relative_humidity": 50
  }
}
```

The answer is a piece of JSON code.

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Load</button>
<p class="text">Text replaced by a response</p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('.btn').click(function () {

    $('.text').text('Loading...');

    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://mmb.some-url.com:8082/api/calculators/hc/calculate',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Origin": "*",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer token-code-here',
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "product_id": "hc",
        "dimensions": {
          "length": 1111,
          "standard_lengths": "yes"
          },
        "heating": {
          "temp_water_in": 75,
          "temp_water_out": 65,
          "temp_room": 20
          },
        "cooling": {
          "temp_water_in": 7,
          "temp_water_out": 12,
          "temp_room": 27,
          "relative_humidity": 50
          }
      }),
      success: function (data) {
        $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(data));
      }});
  });
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: Your code seems fine in isolation. Note that a 405 error means you're using a HTTP verb which the server does not expect for that endpoint. In this case, POST. Try GET, or maybe PUT. Refer to the documentation

Comment: My guess is that you can't call an API like this directly from the browser, even with CORS enabled. This is always difficult to achieve. APITester does not perform the call directly from your browser. It sends your instructions server-side (to `https://apitester.com/checks/test`, if you check your network inspector), performs the API call server-side, then sends the result back to the browser for display. That's exactly what you should do.

Comment: Your API doesn't support POST request check you API docs to know which HTTP verbs are allowed.

Comment: 405 after deployment means it is connected just you cannot access the method due to security issues.You need to call the main url where you have deployed your app and not hit the api directly. if you are using free server go for heroku.It is quite easy and handy to use.